# Solution of the Beast in Disguise $y'=x-y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'=x-y^2$
Its a first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation. The solution is given here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%3Dx-y%5E2&x=0&y=0. 
But how is it obtained? Whats happening here? Direct answers are appreciated, If not possible I will do with a few links to know more about these kind of equations. And some more personified help.

Comment: You've effectively just specified an easy-to-state difficult-to-calculate integral. Integrals don't have to be nice even if they're easy to state.

Comment: Yes, its easy to state, but its the hard part that's where I am interested in.

Comment: It's a Ricatti equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99850/how-can-i-solve-the-differential-equation-yy2-fx?rq=1

Comment: I appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$y'=x-y^2$ is Riccati ODE classically solved thanks to a change of function, in this case :
$$y=\frac{f'}{f}$$
$y'=\frac{f''}{f}-\frac{f'^2}{f^2}$
$$\frac{f''}{f}-\frac{f'^2}{f^2}=x-\left(\frac{f'}{f}\right)^2$$
$$f''=x\:f$$
This is an Airy ODE. The solutions are the Airy functions $\text{Ai}(x)$ and $\text{Bi}(x)$ which derivatives are  $\text{Ai}'(x)$ and $\text{Bi}'(x)$
$$y(x)=\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{c_1 \text{Ai}'(x) +c_2 \text{Bi}'(x)  }{c_1 \text{Ai}(x)  +c_2 \text{Bi}(x)  }$$

Alternatively all can be expressed in terms of Bessel functions. So, $y(x)=\frac{f'}{f}$ is a fraction of Bessel functions.

Comment: I am not much affiliated to this deep mathematics but as always, thanks for the heads up. A more simplified version will be as good.

Comment: I doubt that "a more simplified version" exists. If your problem is raised on a lower level of mathepatics, probably there is something fishy. Are you sure of the ODE ?. Is there no information in addition which allows to bring to a less general case (for example particular boundary conditions or something else) ?. Can you give more details about the context of the question. The best should be to give the original wording of the problem from which the ODE is coming.

Comment: Accepted it as answer. The question came to my mind, I tried to solve it, I couldn't, Then I viewed its solution in wolfram alpha,. Hence i wanted to know more about ODE, and the method to obtain the solution.

Comment: It is valuable to know more about ODEs. Also it is valuable to know more about special functions because many solutions of ODEs involve special functions. The ODE $f''=xf$ is a good example requiring some knowlege about Airy or Bessel Functions. There is a paper for general public : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales