# Solving differential equation $y''(x)+Q(x)y(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

How to solve the following differential equation 
$$y''(x)+Q(x)y(x)=0$$

And how to find exact solution $y(x)$ in terms of special functions?

Comment: For any $Q(x)$ ?

Comment: Generic answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668630/the-general-solution-of-the-given-second-order-differential-equation

Comment: If you do not know an particular solution $(y_1(x))$ for the equation , there is no known general solution for the equation for $Q(x)$. If you want to check my question that related to this problem. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99850/how-can-i-solve-the-differential-equation-yy2-fx

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici this equation is from quantum mechanics, and I think there is a general method for solving this equation for any $Q(x)$. There are many method  for special $Q(x)$, for instance $Q(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: OK for some specific functions such as $Q(x)=\frac{1}{x^n}$,  $Q(x)={x^n}$

Comment: @Mathlover Particular solution for any General $Q(x)$? or Particular solution for particular $Q(x)$?

Comment: If you know any particular solution $y_p(x)$ that solves $y''(x)+Q(x)y(x)=0$ , You will find the general solution of your equation. There is no closed known solution method to find the particular solution if $Q(x)$ is not given.  Of course there are a lot of endless series methods exist to solve the equation but no closed formula for general $Q(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not precise enough formulated... Are you looking at ANY $Q(x)$, or you are interested in polynomial $Q(x)$, etc...

Such type of equation appears routinely in quantum mechanics, when calculating eigenstates and eigen-energies of one-dimensional systems, or corresponds to the three-dimensional systems via the so-called radial Schroedinger equation (spherical coordinates, or alike)...

There are particular cases when this is solvable in closed form (special functions, etc), but for a general solution, only approximations are available (see the WKB method and similar).

The literature is huge on this topic (regarding analytical solutions): the WKB, operational calculus (again, hard to tackle the general case), Laplace transform technique, homotopy method... You can search on the web for them, and you find plenty of papers...

If you look at a numerical solution, again, depending on the characteristics of $Q(x)$, many numerical issues can appear the hinder obtaining the solution to, say, machine precision in reasonable computer time and memory.

All in all, you need be more specific about $Q(x)$, otherwise the topic is too large to be addressed in a simpler manner...

Comment: OK, I Find solution $y(x)=\frac{1}{(-Q(x))^{1/4}}\bigg[A_1 exp(\int \sqrt{-Q(x)}dx)+A_2 exp(-\int \sqrt{-Q(x)}dx) \bigg]$  it is acceptable whenever $Q(x)$ is large

Comment: something along these lines...You could add the integral bounds too. For more details on this, see the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation.